# R extract numbers while leaving blanks

Tags: r

Consider the input `c("foo 1", "bar 2", "baz")`. I'd like to turn this into `c(1,2,NA)` (basically extract the numbers from each string, or if none exist turn it into an `NA`). My first pass looks like this:

```
funNums = as.numeric(
                  regmatches(x$Fun,
                    regexpr('\\d+', x$Fun, perl = T)))
```

where `x$Fun` is my input vector. The output I get from this though is `c(1,2)` since `regmatches` throws away things which don't match. How can I get it to include `NA`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
X <- c("foo 1", "bar 2", "baz")
as.numeric(gsub("([^[:digit:]]*)", "", X))
# [1]  1  2 NA
```

(Do be aware that when passed a string like `"1 to 2"`, this will return the number `12`, which may not be what you'd like it to do.)

Comment: To avoid the potential issue of "1 pass 2" becoming 12 one could use a pattern that left the spaces in: `"([^[:digit:] ]*)"` since `as.numeric` ignores trailing and leading spaces.

Comment: @Dwin -- Very clever. `"1 to 2"` would then become `NA`.

Comment: And thinking further I doubt the parens are needed.

Comment: @DWin -- And even further, neither is the `*` quantifier, unless the matches are to be replaced with spaces.